# initialization of the default value of calendar date

Tags: calendar, primefaces

I have of problem the the primefaces calendar component.
In a postconstruct method of my managed bean, I set a default value for the calendar component. This default value is not displayed in my page and the displayed field is null.

implementation used Mojarra 2.1.7-jboss and primefaces 3.2.

example:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dashboardController")
@ViewScoped
public class DashboardController implements Serializable {

/**
* selected date To
*/
private Date selectedDateTo;

@PostConstruct
public void postconstruct() {
        selectedDateTo = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
}

// getter setter
```

Comment: try `selectedDateTo=new Date();` instead...

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dashboardController")
@ViewScoped
public class DashboardController implements Serializable {

/**
* selected date To
*/
private Date selectedDateTo = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

/**
 * getter
 */
public Date getSelectedDateTo() {
    return selectedDateTo;
}

/**
 * setter
 */
public void setSelectedDateTo(Date selectedDateTo) {
    this.selectedDateTo = selectedDateTo;
}
```

remove the PostConstruct method and just create a Date object from Calendar as shown above. it worked just fine for me, displaying the current date as the default date on the calendar component.